# How to run multiple multiplayer games (servers) on one server in node.js

Tags: node.js, express, socket.io

So I have a website and I have done 2 multiplayer games with socket.io and express which are separate from each other and I was thinking about to move them to the site. So how I am supposed to run my site and the games in it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here are some ideas:

- Run the game servers on different TCP ports, expose them to the Internet and connect to them like `https://example.com:1234/`. Probably the easiest and works well.
- Integrate the game servers with your web server. Can be hard.
- Run the game servers on different TCP ports and make the web server proxy requests/websockets to the right game server. Only use this if there's firewall issues with different ports.

Without knowing the specifics of your servers, we can't help much more than this.